# のちほどスタッフは彼女の元を去りました。 Could someone explain how 元を去りました。works here?

Tags: vocabulary, verbs, nouns

のちほどスタッフは彼女の元を去りました。
This was written on screen at the end of a video skit about a girl at a 女子会 at a restaurant.
元を去りました means the staff left her alone?
If anyone could translate this sentence, I would appreciate it.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-_QQeSdHjqI&feature=BFa&list=WLFF0791364AE7F1A1&lf=feedwll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What should be analysed is not `元を去りました` but `彼女の元を去りました`.

- 彼女の元: her side
- 去る: to leave

Combining them yields: `彼女の元を去りました`: "(the staff) left her side" (no longer with her)